# Theme Configuration is missing in Magento 2.1.5

Tags: magento-2.1

I am developing an e-commerce store using Magento 2.1.5, I installed Magento & theme. Everything works fine with Magento default theme, but when I am trying to enable my new installed theme, there is no option to enable them. I have gone through Magento documentation but those steps are not working for me.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html

But in my case the screen is like this.

[image]

My themes list here.

[image]

Please help me soon.

Thanks

Comment: it is in content -> Design -> configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the [documentation for version 2.1](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html) - themes are assigned under the Content tab now.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Go to Content > Configuration (Design)

[image]

2. On Design Configuration Screen Click Edit.

[image]

Here you can change theme. It's really confusing.

Dear Danny &  Rizwan, Thanks for your support. You really save my day.

Thanks